# SpringToolsSuite's Debugger does not show the code anymore

Tags: java, debugging, spring-tool-suite

I am debugging a spring boot app in STS. Unfortunately when i reach a breakpoint, the IDE does not show the code, like it did before. I have already added the /src folder to the Source Lookup Path in the Debug Configurations dialog.

Comment: hard to diagnose here, would need more details. What caused this change in behavior? Does it happen for every project? What happens if you delete the launch config and create a new one?

Comment: The problem exists only in this project. I dont know what caused this behavior. I have already resetted the debug perspective.

Comment: Everything other project in the same workspace works fine with the debugger?

Comment: What about deleting the launch config for this project? did that change anything?

Comment: Yes it shows each line of a simple java application

Comment: did you try deleting the launch config? If so, I would suggest to file a bug at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ide/issues and attach the project that causes the issue, so that we can try to reproduce.